# Moving kitchen opposite bathroom

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, load-bearing

Initially I wanted to convert the flat to a one bedroom, but it doesn't seem feasible due to lack of fire escape route from what would have been the bedroom (flat is higher than 4.5m from the ground).. I would still want to move the kitchen to the other side. My thought was to connect the kitchen to the pipework in the bathroom which is on the other side of the wall. Now as the wall separating these two rooms is solid (most likely structural) wall, will I need a structural engineer to run the pipes through the wall to the bathroom?
I've attached current and proposed floorplan and a picture of the pipes along the structural wall (thickest one waste water, others cold/hot water pipes)

Any other ideas to make use of the floorarea are more than welcome.

Thanks,
Sonja

[image: Current floorplan]

[image: Proposed floorplan]

[image: pipes structural wall]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where's the piping (sink, bathtub/shower, toilet) in the bathroom?

Comment: How is the wall constructed (drywall+studs, concrete block, poured concrete, last+plaster, ...)? Are the pipes already in the wall, or do they come from somewhere else (a picture may help)? Have you located both the vent and drain pipes?

Comment: Hi, the sink is along the structural wall, bathtub and toilet on the opposite wall.

Comment: Separate drainage for toilet and sink. Can take some picture later when I'm at home. The wall is a solid brick wall and as far as I know no pipes go through or are inside the wall.